# cshell: running cat on a large text file inside backticks gives 'word too long'

Tags: perl, shell, command-line-arguments, csh, backticks

I have a file that has fairly long lines. The longest line has length 4609:

```
% perl -nle 'print length' ~/very_large_file | sort -nu | tail -1
4609
```

Now, when I just run `cat ~/very_large_file` it runs fine. But when I put inside backticks, it gives a 'word too long' error

```
% foreach line (`cat ~/very_large_file`)
Word too long.

% set x = `cat ~/very_large_file`
Word too long.
```

Is there an alternative to using backticks in `csh` to process each line of such a file?

**Update** My problem was solved by using a different language, but I still couldn't get the reason for the failing csh. Just came across [this](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/) page that describes the manner of finding ARG_MAX. In particular, the `getconf` command is useful. Of course, I am *still* not sure whether this limit is the root cause, and if the limit applies to the languages other than `csh`.

Comment: What are you doing with each line?  (Inevitably, someone will point you to http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/.)

Comment: Are you using csh or tcsh?  I tried this using tcsh 6.17.02 on a file with a single 4609-character line and didn't get any "word too long" errors.  Slurping the entire file into `$x` might still cause problems.  But since you have Perl, why not just use that?  It's a *much* better scripting language than csh.

Comment: i need to maintain this shell script, and honestly i have a hard time doing it! The foreach loop is doing a lot of (mostly) text operations, and this bug has appeared only recently...yes, i am planning to rewrite the entire thing in perl, but if there is a way of substituting the `cat` operation  with something non buggy, it would greatly help me in the short term.

Comment: Hi again...i overlooked your other query abt the shell. i am using tcsh, on rh4, so probably it is an older version...let me look up and get back...

Comment: In the old Sun/Solaris CSH man page, there was a section called LIMITS that specified how big a line of data could be processed both as characters and words (if I remember correctly). Maybe your system's man page has a similar section. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't mean to beat an old horse, but if you're scripting do consider moving to `bash`, `zsh` or even Korn. csh [has disadvantages](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/CshTop10.txt).

What you can try without abandoning csh completely:

- Move to tcsh if you're with regular old (very old) csh.
- Recompile tcsh with a longer word length (the default is 1000 bytes, I think) or with dynamic allocation.
- If possible move the line processing to a secondary script or program and write that loop like this:

  cat ~/very_large_file | xargs secondary_script

Comment: Hi...i am not sure if i can recompile the tcsh as i dont have root priveleges...but i will try your other solutions and get back...

Comment: @Unos Rebuilding the shell to have a longer maximum word length is not going to help you, because this is a kernel thing, probably `NCARGS` or `ARG_MAX` in your `<sys/param.h>` include file. Although a few kernels allow this to grow dynamically, most do not, and you should always be prepared to use an `xargs` approach, or else find some other way not to supply everything on the command line, such as reading the data from standard input instead.

Comment: @Unos: You don't meed root privileges to build `tcsh` from source and install it somewhere under your home directory.

Comment: @all, I just rewrote the whole script in perl. I personally liked the `xargs` solution, but if I did that, I would've needed to maintain one more csh script (one too many). The links about disadvantages of csh made me thank God that I did not come across its more cryptic problems. Thanks everyone :)